# How to get string variable in quotes in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I want to get string in quotes, use backslashes :

```
>>> "\"2\""
'"2"'
```

Looks good, but no idea how to do it with string variable

```
>>> a=2
>>> "\"a\""
'"a"'
```

Of course I want same '2' not 'a'

Comment: ...what? Why *would* a string literal of a string literal evaluate to the value of that identifier? There's no *"Of course"* about this.

Comment: `a` is not a string variable.

Comment: ok so let's say a="2"

Comment: You can use `+` to concatenate strings, but this whole thing smells like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you want to put quotes around a variable's value?

Comment: "\"+a+\"" does not work too

Comment: `"\"" + "hello" + "\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, you can use [%-formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) with the `%` operator.

```
a = "2"
b = "\"%s\"" % a

print("Before:\t%s" % a)
print("After:\t%s"  % b)
```

---

In Python 3, you would use the built-in [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting):

```
a = "2"
b = "\"{}\"".format(a)

print("Before:\t{}".format(a))
print("After:\t{}".format(b))
```

**Note:** %-formatting still works in Python 3 but `format()` is typically preferred.

---

Alternatively, in either Python 2 or 3, the same can be accomplished, albeit less Pythonically, using string concatenation with the `+` operator:

```
a = "2"
b = "\"" + a + "\""

print("Before:\t" + a)
print("After:\t"  + b)
```

---

All three approaches output the following:

```
Before: 2
After:  "2"
```